# Facebook instant article URL Claim

Tags: facebook, facebook-instant-articles

I'm not getting the exact way to claim the URL in Facebook Instant Article. Site is using https and there is not option to change http to https. Also shown an error.

[image: Error when claim URL]

Let me know where I'm wrong. Or any suggestion for me.

Comment: “because the site has minimal readership” ... Ur site to unimportant to begin with, so Facebook be saying, “no thank you” ... what is unclear about this?

Answer (score -1):

Try to enter the site without the protocol https or http just www.domainname.com

But I think the mistake is in the other place..

Just Bring More Than 20000-30000 traffic in 24 hours through Facebook groups or bring paid traffic to your site then you gonna get approve.

As far as I know, the minimum readership is 10000-15000 traffic

Comment: Please dont use stackoverflow for these kind of posts about traffic to websites